# How to merge rows inside the table content?

Tags: tables, multirow

I tried to make a table like the one shown below but when I include `multirow` it gives me normal type of tables yet. I mean in the last row, the horizontal line appears while it is merged.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Type} & \textbf{Max} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Notes} \\
\hline
- & 10 & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 1} \\ 
\hline
- &  & V & \\
\hline
- & - & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 2} \\
\hline
 - &  & V &  \\
\hline
- & - & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 3} \\
\hline
- & 12 & V &   \\
\hline
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \multirow{2}{*}{}\\
\hline
  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
2.2 & - & pF &  \\
\hline
$\pm$1 & 10 & $\mu$A & Note4 \\
\hline  
\end{tabular*}
\captionof{table}{Characteristics}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your code is not compilable. Please fix that. And for sure we don't need all that packages to help you. Please kick out everything except stuff causing your error!

Comment: If you know some German (as I suspect from your name) I recommend the book `Tabellen mit LaTeX` by Herbert Voss (he is also a user here) or the corresponding english translation `Typesetting tables with LaTeX` ;-)

Comment: The last `\multirow` of yours is trying to merge the last and some not existing lower row. I guess, it should one row up or refer to minus 2 rows (possible to do that, but I am not sure about how). Just move it up in the second last row in order to get fifth double row.

Comment: Please fix your MWE: `\begin{document}` is missing; lots of packages, which are not needed, not even `tabularx`; wrong number of columns; overfull `\hbox`; ...

Comment: @Klara: There is `tabular*`, which does the same as in the MWE. `tabularx` is needed for columns that are stretched to the available space, see column specifier `X`.

Comment: @Klara: Please remove the unnecessary packages (`fontspec`, `graphicx`, `xcolor`, `calc`, `float`, ...). Run the example through LaTeX and fix the obvious errors and warnings: There are rows with more cells than the number of specified columns; overfull `\hbox` warning; ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a problem of using `\cline` instead of `\hline`, and the `m` specifier instead of `p`. Once again I suggest you use the `siunitx` package to type `μA`, because the micro symbol is `upright` μ. I suppressed the invocation of tabularx since you have no `X` column, and loading `textcomp` which is harmful with fontspec. The `flushleft` environment is useless here: just use `table` with the `H` option, and it won't float.

Finally I thought the table would be better looking if the caption were also flushleft. If you want it centred flushright with respect to the table, you can use the `threeparttable` environment. I give an example of caption at the bottom left and right corners of the table.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    %\usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[british]{babel}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{float}
    %\usepackage{gensymb}
    \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
    \usepackage{multirow}

    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}


    \begin{document}
    Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

    \begin{table}[H]
    \sffamily\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,position = below, font = sf}
    \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1cm}|m{3.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Max} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Notes} \\
    \hline
    -- & 10 & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 1} \\
    \cline{1-3}
    -- & & V & \\
    \hline
    -- & -- & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 2} \\
    \cline{1-3}
     -- & & V & \\
    \hline
    -- & -- & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 3} \\
    \cline{1-3}
    -- & 12 & V & \\
    \hline
      & & & \multirow{2}{*}{}\\
    \cline{1-3}
      & & & \\
    \hline
    2.2 & -- & \si{\pico\farad} & \multirow{2}{*}{Note4} \\
    \cline{1-3}
    $\pm$1 & 10 & \si{\micro\ampere} & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Characteristics}
    \end{table}
    Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

    \begin{table}[H]
    \sffamily\captionsetup{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=false,position = below, font = sf}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1cm}|m{3.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Max} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Notes} \\
    \hline
    -- & 10 & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 1} \\
    \cline{1-3}
    -- & & V & \\
    \hline
    -- & -- & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 2} \\
    \cline{1-3}
     -- & & V & \\
    \hline
    -- & -- & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 3} \\
    \cline{1-3}
    -- & 12 & V & \\
    \hline
      & & & \multirow{2}{*}{}\\
    \cline{1-3}
      & & & \\
    \hline
    2.2 & -- & \si{\pico\farad} & \multirow{2}{*}{Note4} \\
    \cline{1-3}
    $\pm$1 & 10 & \si{\micro\ampere} & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Characteristics}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have extra `&` on lines with empty cells (don't take in account width `X` modifier and `standalone` package).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Type} & \textbf{Max} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline
- & 10 & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 1} \\ \cline{1-3}
- & & V & \\ \hline
- & - & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 2} \\ \cline{1-3}
- & & V & \\ \hline
- & - & V & \multirow{2}{*}{Note 3} \\ \cline{1-3}
- & 12 & V & \\ \hline
 & & & \multirow{2}{*}{}\\ \hline
 & & & \\ \hline
2.2 & - & pF &  \\ \hline
$\pm$1 & 10 & $\mu$A & Note4 \\ \hline  
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]